# Group Policy: Group-specific desktop shortcuts that only applies to a single computer

Tags: group-policy

I can't believe I'm here, but I am, begging for help. :)

I thought this would be simple...

anyways...

AD Group: "Blue Team"
Members: "Papa Smurf"

AD Group: "Red Team"
Members: "BSD devil dude"

Computer: RDSSERVER (2019 RDS Server session host; old school TS)

I would like members of the "Blue Team" to have a desktop shortcut called "bluestuff.lnk" (I'm copying this from a UNC path; this works fine); I would like members of "Red Team" to have a desktop shortcut called "redstuff.lnk"... but any shortcut should only be on the RDSSERVER desktop.

Members of Blue Team reside in an OU called Blue Team; ditto for Red Team.  i'd rather not have to use AD groups as these users are already in the OU, but I can't seem to use the OU and have it apply only to the RDSSERVER using the Security Filtering in the Scope.

EDIT:

Pretty sure I had (have) the following GP hierarchy:

- RDS Servers (OU):

  - "Red Team Shortcuts" (linked/not enforced) (loopback processing: merge) > Security Filtering: "Red Team" group.
  - "Blue Team Shortcuts" (linked/not enforced) (loopback processing: merge) > Security Filtering: "Blue Team" group.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out.  Key was **item-level targeting** under the Common tab.

Ended up using the "RDS Servers" OU, as was suggested/tried before with loopback processing (Merge) enabled; RDSSERVER exists in the "RDS Servers" OU obviously.

I created two GPOs below that parent OU GPO:

- Red Team Shortcuts (Security Filtering default "Authenticated Users"), but under the Common tab of the Users Configuration > Preferences > File, I chose item-level targeting with "User OU" selected and the "Red Team" OU as the value.
- Ditto for Blue Team Shortcuts with a different item-level targeting value and shortcut.

It didn't seem to like the item-level targeting > "User Group" for some reason, but it's late/I'm tired and don't really care at this point.

Comment: Glad you figured something out. It sure seems like what I suggested should have been working.  But sometimes Windows doesn't cooperate with what what you think it should do.

Answer (score 2):

You need to enable [**Loopback processing**](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/askds/2013/02/08/circle-back-to-loopback/) policy in either merge or replace. This changes the OUs that are considered when a user login.

So by default **user policies** will be pulled from the **users OU** (or parent OUs).  In merge mode user policies would be pulled form the user OU, and computer OU.  In replace mode user policies will only come from the computer OU.

With that in place you can create policies in the OU containing your RDS server with filtering based on the security groups, and that should apply the correct policies.

Comment: I swear I did this already.  I created a new "RDS Servers" OU, slapped RDSSERVER in there, then created a new GP called "Blue Team Shortcuts" under the RDS Servers OU.  Edit > Scope > Security Filtering: removed Authenticated Users, added Blue Team.  This worked.  But then I added another GP called "Red Team Shortcuts" with the same settings as above (obv. subbing out Blue Team group for Red Team group) and _both_ were applying.  I tried swapping Merge and Replace on both, but couldn't prevent Papa Smurf from getting redstuff.lnk on his desktop.

Comment: see above for GP hierarchy

Comment: Honestly, I might be tempted to just do it with a login script if it is being a pain.  It should be easy enough to write a quick powershell script that checks the computer name, and group membership, and then copy a file, or create a shortcut.

Comment: Bro, I know.  I also think that I could just do a local policy on the RDS server itself that checks for group membership, but my god, I want (scratch that: need) this to work... I earned my MCSE in NT 4.0 for crying out loud lol